# How to save mxworkflow editor as Xml using javascript

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

Iam using mxWorkflow -Editor to draw workflow process

then i tried to save the  workflow as xml but it is not working

i tried this

```
  function GetXML(container)
{
    var graph = new mxGraph(container);
    var enc = new mxCodec();
    var node = enc.encode(graph.getModel());

    var model = graph.getModel();
    try
    {
       // var graph = new mxGraph(container);
        graph.model.addListener(mxEvent.CHANGE, function (sender, evt) {

            var changes = evt.getProperty('edit').changes;

            for (var i = 0; i < changes.length; i++) {
                var change = changes[i];

                if (change instanceof mxChildChange &&
                  change.change.previous == null) {
                    graph.startEditingAtCell(change.child);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    finally
    {
        // Updates the display

        model.endUpdate();
       // graph.getModel().endUpdate();
    }


// Adds an option to view the XML of the graph
document.body.appendChild(mxUtils.button('View XML', function()
{
    var encoder = new mxCodec();
    var node = encoder.encode(graph.getModel());
    mxUtils.popup(mxUtils.getXml(node), true);
}));
```

I've looked at few posts & documentation , but didn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

use function `mxUtils.getPrettyXml`

```js
var button = mxUtils.button('View XML', function() {
    var encoder = new mxCodec();
    var node = encoder.encode(graph.getModel());
    mxUtils.popup(mxUtils.getPrettyXml(node), true);
});
document.appendChild(button);
```